# How to import a group of layers from a XCF to another XCF in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I have an XCF file that contains a group of layers, full of layers and of others groups of layers.

I have another XCF file in which I would want to put the contents of the first one, keeping it editable (*i.e.: * I want to be able to navigate through the layers of the first XCF, to colorize some of them, etc.: so the tree of layers must be available).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open both XCF files.
2. In the XCF with the layer group, click and drag the layer group from the layers panel onto the other image tab along the top (do not release the mouse button).
3. When the other document window opens, drop the layer group onto the image window.

Unfortunately I can't do a screen recording of this to show you, since my screen recording software interferes with GIMP's drag and drop functionality in Windows. But I did manage to take a screenshot of dropping a layer group from one document into another.

[image]